# Get username machine name and timestamp into excel

Tags: powershell

I'm working on a powershell script to record when a user logs in and record username, server they logged into, and a timestamp,

```
$user = $env:username
$machine = $env:computername
$timestamp = get-date
```

How could I combine all three into a single line and export it to a CSV with the correct colums?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn the data into an object and then use the `Export-CSV` cmdlet.

```
[pscustomobject]@{
    User = $env:username
    Machine = $env:computername
    Timestamp = get-date
 } | Export-CSV C:\Example\path.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 3):

This will do what you requested:

```
#requires -Version 3

[PSCustomObject]$Csv = @{
  User=$env:UserName
  Machine=$env:ComputerName
  TimeStamp=(Get-Date)
}
$Csv | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path C:\temp\ex.csv
```

(One-liner)

```
[PsCustomObject]@{User=$env:UserName;Machine=$env:ComputerName;TimeStamp=(Get-Date)} | Export-Csv -Path $Path -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 1):

It's also worth noting that you can append a CSV in the same way, which may be more what you're looking for. To do this add the `-Append` flag/option.

Comment: `Append` is a parameter of `Export-CSV` rather than the name as `Append` isn't an [approved verb](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714428(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Thank you. Edited for the sake of not misleading.